# Incapacitating Dahl Quest

Tags: prey

Towards the end of the game, you can incapacitate Dahl instead of outright killing him. This opens up an option to leave the station, as well as allow for any crew members you've saved to leave.

I'm a little confused on the events here. I went with the following ending, so keep this in mind:

> use the advanced Nullwave to destroy the Typhon

The quest for incapacitating Dahl sticks around for most of the endgame stuff, and for me it was sitting on "wait for Dahl's signal to leave" or something like that.  However, at no time during the ending sequences did the quest update for me to leave that way. I noticed during the ending cutscene that a shuttle did leave Talos 1, but the quest just stuck around in that waiting state until the very end. Did I miss some other queues, or based on the ending I chose, is this intentional?

Answer (score 2):

> based on the ending I chose, is this intentional?

Correct. If you chose the other ending, then Dahl contacts you immediately after pressing the button. You then have a timer to get to the shuttle.

Massive spoilers:

> Because using the Nullwave resolves everything immediately, there is no need for the simulation to continue. But after setting the self-destruct you still have the choice of whether and how to escape, and Alex wants to see what you do.